# Typesetting binary arithmetic

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I'm stuck trying to typeset the following in math mode. I cannot get the spacing correct.

```
       0100   [4 in decimal]
     x 1100   [12 in decimal]
     ------
  +    0000   [0100 x 0]
  +   0000    [0100x 0, shifted left]
  +  0100     [0100x 1, shifted left two positions]
  + 0100      [0100x 1, shifted left three positions]
  =========
    0110000   [48 decimal]
```

Can this be achieved in math mode, or is is better / easier to just stick with pre-formatted text?

Comment: What did you try before? Looks like either an `array` or a few `\hphantom{0}` should do.

Comment: \hphantom did it. Still a novice with LaTeX, thanks for introducing me to a useful element. I'd guessed there must be something like that, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\hphantom` has already been suggested, but making this look really nice was a fun diversion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\0}{\phantom{0}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
 && 0100 & \quad && \text{[\,4 in decimal]}\\
 && \underline{\strut{}\times 1100} &&& \text{[\,12 in decimal]}\\
 & + & 0000 &&& \text{[\,$0100\times 0$]}\\
 & + & 0000\0 &&& \text{[\,$0100\times 0$, shifted left]}\\
 & + & 0100\0\0 &&& \text{[\,$0100\times 1$, shifted left two positions]}\\
 & \underline{\strut+} & \underline{\strut\0 0100\0\0\0} &&&
       \text{[\,$0100\times 1$, shifted left three positions]}\\
 && \0 0110000 &&& \text{[\,48 decimal]}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- yes, stolen, i do believe.  your approach, while solid, has a couple of flaws -- you should have used `\times` in the explications, and the widths of the rules don't encompass the signs of operation as posited in the original question.  (details, sir, details!)

Comment: Better yet: ``\begingroup\catcode`?=\active\def?{\hphantom{0}}\begin{alignat*}{2}`` `;-)`

Comment: @egreg -- oh, golly, yes, but for once, i was trying to do something entirely within the latex canon, and not drop back to plain tex, as is my wont.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}*{9}{c@{}}>{\quad$[}l<{]$}@{}}
 &    && & &0&1&0&0&   4 in decimal\\
 & &&\times & &1&1&0&0&   12 in decimal\\
\cline{5-9}
+& & & & &0&0&0&0&   0100 x 0\\
+& & & &0&0&0&0& &   0100x 0, shifted left\\
+& & &0&1&0&0& &   & 0100x 1, shifted left two positions\\
+&\phantom{0} &0&1&0&0& &     &&0100x 1, shifted left three positions\\
\cline{3-9}
\noalign{\kern2pt}
\cline{3-9}
 & &0&1&1&0&0&0&0&   48 decimal
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun! `;-)`

The table is typeset by

```
\binmult{4}{12}
```

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\binmult}{mm}
 {
  \david_binmult:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_david_binmult_first_int
\int_new:N \l_david_binmult_second_int
\int_new:N \l_david_binmult_bits_int
\int_new:N \l__david_binmult_cycle_int

\tl_new:N \l_david_binmult_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_david_binmult_second_tl
\tl_new:N \l_david_binmult_second_rev_tl
\tl_new:N \l_david_binmult_product_tl
\tl_new:N \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl

\seq_new:N \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq
\seq_new:N \l_david_binmult_partial_descr_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__david_binmult_pad:Nn
 {% #1 should be a tl, #2 an integer denomination
  \prg_replicate:nn { \int_max:nn { #2 - \tl_count:N #1 } { 0 } }
   {
    \tl_put_left:Nn #1 { 0 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \david_binmult:nn
 {
  % store the data
  \int_set:Nn \l_david_binmult_first_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_david_binmult_second_int { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_david_binmult_first_tl { \int_to_bin:n { #1 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_david_binmult_second_tl { \int_to_bin:n { #2 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_david_binmult_product_tl { \int_to_bin:n { #1 * #2 } }
  % pad the factors
  \int_set:Nn \l_david_binmult_bits_int
   {
    \int_max:nn { \tl_count:N \l_david_binmult_first_tl } 
                { \tl_count:N \l_david_binmult_second_tl }
   }
  % pad the product
  \__david_binmult_pad:Nn \l_david_binmult_product_tl
   {
    2*\l_david_binmult_bits_int-1
   }
  \__david_binmult_pad:Nn \l_david_binmult_first_tl { \l_david_binmult_bits_int }
  \__david_binmult_pad:Nn \l_david_binmult_second_tl { \l_david_binmult_bits_int }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_david_binmult_second_rev_tl \l_david_binmult_second_tl
  \tl_reverse:N \l_david_binmult_second_rev_tl
  % compute the partial products
  \seq_clear:N \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_david_binmult_partial_descr_seq
  \int_zero:N \l__david_binmult_cycle_int
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_david_binmult_second_rev_tl
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = 0 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq
       {
        \prg_replicate:nn { \l_david_binmult_bits_int } { 0 }
        \prg_replicate:nn { \l__david_binmult_cycle_int } { \exp_not:N \hphantom {0} }
       }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq
       {
        \tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_first_tl
        \prg_replicate:nn { \l__david_binmult_cycle_int } { \exp_not:N \hphantom {0} }
       }
     }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_david_binmult_partial_descr_seq
     {
      [
      $\tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_first_tl \times ##1$
      \int_case:nnF { \l__david_binmult_cycle_int }
       {
        {0}{}
        {1}{,~shifted~left}
       }
       {,~shifted~left~\david_binmult_number:n { \l__david_binmult_cycle_int }~positions}
      ]
     }
    \int_incr:N \l__david_binmult_cycle_int
   }
  % build the tabular
  \tl_clear:N \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl
   {
    & $\tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_first_tl$ & [$#1$~in~decimal] \\
    & ${\times}\;\tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_second_tl$ & [$#2$~in~decimal] \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-2}
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl
     {
      $+$ &
      \seq_item:Nn \l_david_binmult_partial_products_seq { ##1 } &
      \seq_item:Nn \l_david_binmult_partial_descr_seq { ##1 } \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl
   {
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}
    & $\tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_product_tl$ & [$\int_to_arabic:n { #1 * #2 }$~in~decimal]
   }
  % print the table 
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c r l @{}}
  \tl_use:N \l_david_binmult_tablebody_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \david_binmult_number:n
 {
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {0}{zero}
    {1}{one}
    {2}{two}
    {3}{three}
    {4}{four}
    {5}{five}
    {6}{six}
    {7}{seven}
    {8}{eight}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\binmult{4}{12}

\bigskip

\binmult{12}{12}

\bigskip

\binmult{13}{35}

\end{document}
```

[image]