# Automatic "school" arithmetic with binary numbers

Tags: xlop

The xlop package provides a way of having addition, multiplication, etc, of base 10 numbers that does all the work out including carry bits and the bar that is above the answer. I am looking for a way to do this, but with binary numbers. Key point: I need it to be automatic, where I just enter the two numbers and all the actual math is done by the computer. I know there are ways to do it manually, that is not useful for what I need.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371995/4427 help?

Comment: The xlop manual states on page 49 that this is planned in a future version, i quote `The features of version 0.3 aren’t definitively fixed but there are some points planned:
• international version for posées;
• opérations from 2 to 36 basis;`

Comment: @egreg hey that does help, at least for multiplying, Ill see if I can modifying it to do adding and subtracting (Don't think it will help for division though)